# Conditionally quote/substitute an expression if not already quoted

Tags: r, eval, metaprogramming, nse, non-standard-evaluation

I'm looking for a way to quote an argument passed to function (consider `substitute()`, `ggplot2`'s `aes()`, `subset()` or `data.table`'s `[` behavior), but do it conditionally - only if not already quoted with `quote()`.

This is because I'd like to easily chain functions, that do not make assumptions whether an argument is previously quoted, or not - but instead substitute it as needed.

Few questions:

1. Why is this a bad idea?
2. Are there already any built-in methods to achieve this goal?
3. The `tryCatch` part is because `is.language` throws an error if an `x` promise evaluates to a non-defined variable. Is there any other/better solution?

What I've come up with:

```
substitute_c <- function(x) {
  e <- suppressWarnings(
    tryCatch({x; FALSE}, 
             error = function(e) TRUE))

  if (e || !is.language(x)) {
    substitute_q(substitute(x), env = parent.frame())
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

How it works:

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)

# Example 1
fn <- function(x) substitute_c(x)
fn2 <- function(y) fn(substitute_c(y))
fn3 <- function(z) fn2(substitute_c(z))

fn(quote(a + b)
fn(a + b)
fn2(a + b)
fn3(quote(a + b))

# Example 2
dtcars <- mtcars %>% as.data.table

subset_test <- function(dt, cols) {
  cols <- substitute_c(cols)
  dt[, eval(cols)]
}

subset_test2 <- function(dt, cols) {
  cols <- substitute_c(cols)
  subset_test(dt, cols)
}

subset_test(dtcars, .(mpg, cyl))
subset_test(dtcars, list(mpg, cyl))
subset_test2(dtcars, .(mpg, cyl))
subset_test2(dtcars, list(mpg, cyl))
```

Comment: There's not going to be a good way for R to guess if you want your parameters evaluated or not. Especially when nesting functions calls. `quote()` isn't really magic, it's just a function that returns an un-evaluated expression when evaluated. That expression doesn't retain any knowledge of how it was created. But all function parameters are really un-evaluated expressions until you evaluate them. Don't make it difficult for readers of your code to guess what's going on; be explicit.

Comment: To answer (1): because it doesn’t compose: what if you *need* to quote a quoted argument again? In other words, how would R know whether or not to quote *that specific argument*? That said, R has some corner cases that already exhibit this bad behaviour (for instance `try`: there’s no way of knowing whether it caught an error or whether its expression returned a `simpleError` object).

Comment: I agree, that it would be troublesome for others, but for personal use it saves me the need of injecting `quote()` anytime I'm calling a function, which is further passing arguments to data.table or ggplot.
Please note that all I need is a way for a non-standard evaluation of an argument, that is simply firstly transformed to quoted expression, and later retained as is - no matter which function I begin with, and which will follow.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - for multiple quoting I still can use `enquote()` in relevant function, or provide such transformed argument while calling.